# Disabling DELETE function in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-delete, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

In one BigQuery Project, I'd like to make sure no-one is able to DELETE any data. 
Is there a known way to avoid DELETE function ? 
I can't regulate that using the IAM access control because I need to provide tp a group the job.User access so that allows running even DELETE jobs...
Which I'm not really confortable with...
I haven't seen anything related to it here yet...
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

You can expose such data via [Authorized Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views) - so users will be able to query data - but not delete, update, etc.